# Wrapping a polling-based asynchronous API as an Awaitable

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, python-trio, python-anyio

Consider some library with an interface like this:

- `RemoteTask.start()`
- `RemoteTask.cancel()`
- `RemoteTask.get_id()`
- `RemoteTask.get_result()`
- `RemoteTask.is_done()`

For example, `concurrent.futures.Future` implements an API like this, but I don't want to assume the presence of a function like `concurrent.futures.wait`.

In traditional Python code, you might need to *poll* for results:

```py
def foo():
   task = RemoteTask()
    while not task.is_done():
        time.sleep(2)
    return task.get_result()
```

Is there some general recommended best-practice technique for wrapping this in an `Awaitable` interface?

The desired usage would be:

```py
async def foo():
    task = RemoteTask()
    return await run_remote_task()
```

I understand that the implementation details might differ across async libraries, so I am open to both general strategies for solving this problem, and specific solutions for Asyncio, Trio, AnyIO, or even Curio.

Assume that this library cannot be easily modified, and must be wrapped.

Comment: Does this work: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=to_thread#asyncio.to_thread  You would write your `async def foo` function's second line as, `return await asyncio.to_thread(run_remote_task)`

Comment: while the awaitable and concurrent version is achievable and works fine, it won't be shorter (in code) as your "traditional" `foo` version.

Comment: @PaulCornelius that's a valid option, although pushing the busy loop to a thread is kind of a last resort.

Comment: I was hoping this method call would eliminate the need for any busy loop.  The `to_thread` call returns an awaitable which becomes done when the function finishes.  You don't need a loop to check when it's done, you can either await it or use `add_done_callback.`

Comment: @PaulCornelius what function are you saying should be sent to run in the thread?

Comment: `run_remote_task`, as in your example.  You didn't elaborate, but I assume that when this function returns the task is done.  When the `to_thread` function returns to the main loop, which will be almost immediate, its returned value is an awaitable.  The awaitable is done when run_remote_task is done.

Comment: @PaulCornelius the problem is that the API does not currently provide a blocking `run_remote_task` function. It _only_ provides asynchronous start/cancel/get-result methods. Hence the need for a polling loop.

Comment: I understand now - the polling loop is not a "might need to" but a "must".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the answer by Matthias says, if there is a way to block waiting for the remote task to complete (something like `task.wait_until_done()`) then you can turn that into an async wait function using the respective libraries' functions to run blocking code in a thread.

Failing that, and assuming that none of those functions block, then polling will still work. If you don't want to handle cancellation then it looks almost identical to the synchronous version and would be very similar across the different frameworks. It looks like this:

```py
async def run_remote_task(*args, poll_interval=0.1):
    task = RemoteTask(*args)
    while not task.is_done():
        await trio.sleep(poll_interval)
    return task.result()
```

The most basic way to handle cancellation is to cancel the remote task if the async task is cancelled, but then don't wait for remote cancellation to complete. For that,  things are still fairly simple:

```py
async def run_remote_task(*args, poll_interval=0.1):
    task = RemoteTask(*args)
    try:
        while not task.is_done():
            await trio.sleep(poll_interval)
        return task.result()
    finally:
        if not task.is_done():
            task.cancel()
```

Again, that would look almost identical on the other frameworks too. Just replace `trio.sleep()` with `asyncio.sleep()` or `anyio.sleep()`.

If you want to wait for the remote cancellation to finish, things are slightly more fiddly. This is what it would look like in Trio (anyio is the same but I'm not sure about asyncio):

```py
async def run_remote_task(*args, poll_interval=0.1):
    task = RemoteTask(*args)
    try:
        while not task.is_done():
            await trio.sleep(poll_interval)
        return task.result()
    finally:
        if not task.is_done():
            with trio.CancelScope(shield=True):
                task.cancel()
                while not task.is_done():
                    await trio.sleep(poll_interval)
```

Comment: asyncio's cancellations are fire-and-forget, thus simply skip the `with CancelScope` context and it'll most likely work.

Answer (score 1):

First possibility: If the library has a way to block until completed (preferably one that doesn't just call `while not task.is_done():` in a tight loop), you can use `anyio.to_thread.run_sync` to avoid blocking your main loop. Disadvantage: Handling cancellations is nontrivial; if the remote library doesn't expect that call from another thread at random times things might break.

Second: If the library has a way to hook up a completion callback, you can set an event from it, which your anyio/trio/asyncio task `await evt.wait()`s for. Arthur's answer shows how to handle cancellation.

Third: If neither of these is true, you might try asking its author to add at least one of those. Busy waiting is not nice!

The fourth method is to fork the remote code's source code and liberally sprinkle it with `import anyio`, `async def` and `await` keywords until calling `await task.run()` Just Works. Cancellations are trivial and most likely involve zero work you shouldn't already be doing anyway (like `try: … finally:` blocks that clean up any left-over state)

Method five would be to split the library into a core that does all the work but doesn't do any I/O by itself, and a wrapper that tells you when you should do some possibly-asynchronous work. This way is called "sans I/O". Several nontrivial popular libraries work that way, e.g. Trio's SSL implementation, or the `httpx` handler for the HTTP protocol. Upside, this way is most useful because you can combine the protocol with others most easily, including writing a simple front-end that behaves just like the original module. Downside, if you start from an existing codebase it's the most work. Cancelling is easy because the sans-io part of the code doesn't wait and thus cannot be cancelled in the first place.

Method four often is way easier than it sounds, I've done it for a lot of not-too-complex libraries.

Comment: These are all great ideas, thank you. I think this package is more like "source available" than "open source", but maybe I can submit a feature request for some kind of `wait()` primitive method. I doubt they'll decide to support `async`/`await` natively any time soon.